# rosrun robopluscom robopluscom

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi , what do I need to install to make the following command : "rosrun robopluscom robopluscom" work? It shows command not found error in my ros Groovy.

Thanks in advance.

[edit] The full context of error is : [rospack] Error: stack/package robopluscom not found

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174118/rosrun-robopluscom-robopluscom/) by [manaXmizery](https://answers.ros.org/users/9931/manaxmizery/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should always post the full text of an error -- as it is printed. "command not found" probably means rosrun was not found? I don't know for sure since you haven't posted the exact error message. If rosrun was not found, you probably don't have it on your path -- have you sourced /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash?

If instead rosrun is telling you that "robopluscom" is not found -- well, is it installed? Is it built? Is it on your path?

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [manaXmizery](https://answers.ros.org/users/9931/manaxmizery/) on 2014-06-19**:
I do apologise. The full error is : [rospack] Error: stack/package robopluscom not found

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-06-19**:
how have you installed robopluscom (I'm not at all familiar with the package -- I've never heard of it)

**Comment by [manaXmizery](https://answers.ros.org/users/9931/manaxmizery/) on 2014-06-20**:
@fergs i haven't installed it yet but i doubt i can find the correct procedures to play :x